# converting a specific string into a list of a class object

Tags: regex, scala

If I have a `case class Point(x: Double, y: Double)`, and `val s="(12,3.5),(33,42),(19.1,3)"`. How to split and convert `s` into something like this?

```
Vector(Point(12,3.5),Point(33,42),Point(19.1,3))
```

(I was thinking first need to split `s` into `"(12,3.5)"`, `"(33,42)"` and `"(19.1,3)"` but I don't know how to do this in a clean way. Afterwards, some scala regular expressions can map each element into `x` and `y` for the `Point` class...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think below code might help you.

```
val s = "(12,3.5),(33,42),(19.1,3)"
val p = "[0-9.]+".r
val result = p.findAllIn(s).map(_.toDouble).grouped(2).map{case Seq(x, y) => Point(x, y)}.toVector
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract tuples from the string, consider

```
val xs = """(\d+(\.\d*)?\,\d+(\.\d*)?)+""".r.findAllIn(s).toArray
Array(12,3.5, 33,42, 19.1,3)
```

To construct the points,

```
for (t <- xs; Array(x,y) = t.split(",")) 
yield Point(x.toDouble, y.toDouble)
```

which delivers

```
Array(Point(12.0,3.5), Point(33.0,42.0), Point(19.1,3.0))
```

Comment: Thanks elm. I think this looks better, as I really need it check the closing of `(` and  `)`.